# Run-time error 13 randomly while iterating emails in a public folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2003

I receive a random run-time error 13 (type mismatch). This routine works most of the time. The folder passed as an argument is legitimate at the time of the failure.

From what I can see in the debugger, `objitem` is missing some of the fields during runtime.  After it break-points in the debugger, I can immediately single-step (re-executing the offending line) and there is no error.

I attempted using `on error goto` to sleep then retry various lines, and the error persists until it stops in the debugger.

I also attempted changing between the For ii and For Each forms of the loop commands.

I also temporarily disabled by anti-virus.

I iterate over a large number of public folders.  My Outlook client is 2003 running under XP, and I am attached to Exchange Server version 7654.

```vb
Sub SearchFolders(objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim objFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim subFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objitem As MailItem
    Dim ii As Integer

' Recurse through all subfolders
    Set objFolders = objFolder.Folders
    For Each subFolder In objFolders
    Call SearchFolders(subFolder)
    Next subFolder

' Search the emails
    For ii = 1 To objFolder.Items.Count
    If objFolder.Items(ii).Class = olMail Then
        If TypeName(objFolder.Items(ii)) <> "MailItem" Then
        MsgBox ("Type mismatch: object s/b MailItem and is " & TypeName(objFolder.Items(ii)))
        GoTo NextdblLoop
        End If
        Set objitem = objFolder.Items(ii)
        CheckEmailForErrorReports (objFolder.Items(ii))
    End If
NextdblLoop:
    Next ii
End Sub
```

Code below is modified per @dmitry suggestions and now works.

```vb
Sub SearchFolders(objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim objFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim subFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Objitem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim ThisItem As Object
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items

' Recurse through all subfolders
    Set objFolders = objFolder.Folders
    For Each subFolder In objFolders
    Call SearchFolders(subFolder)
    Next subFolder

' Search the emails
    Set Items = objFolder.Items
    For ii = 1 To Items.Count
    Set ThisItem = Items.item(ii)
    If ThisItem.Class = olMail Then
        If VarType(ThisItem) = 9 Then GoTo NextdblLoop
        Set Objitem = ThisItem
        CheckEmailForErrorReports (objFolder.Items(ii))
        Set Objitem = Nothing
    End If
    Set ThisItem = Nothing
NextdblLoop:
    Next ii
    Set Items = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not use multiple dot notation; cache the Items collection before entering the loop.

Secondly, release the variables as soon as you are done with them

```
    dim item As Object
    dim Items as Outlook.Items
    set Items = objFolder.Items
    For ii = 1 To Items.Count
        set item = Items.Item(ii)
        If item.Class = olMail Then
            If TypeName(item) <> "MailItem" Then
                'THIS CAN NEVER HAPPEN. The check above is sufficient
                MsgBox ("Type mismatch: object s/b MailItem and is " & TypeName(item))
                GoTo NextdblLoop
            End If
            Set objitem = item 
            CheckEmailForErrorReports (objitem)
            Set objitem = Nothing
        End If
        Set item = Nothing
NextdblLoop:
    Next ii
End Sub
```

Comment: The script stopped failing randomly and I was able to debug it using your changes.  I found two peculiarities:
1) Needed to add 'If VarType(ThisItem) = 9 Then GoTo NextdblLoop' before 'Set Objitem = ThisItem'
2) Needed this syntax for subroutine call: 'CheckEmailForErrorReports (objFolder.Items(ii))'