# Code not executing the loop due to run type error 13 outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to list out all the subjects of emails in a particular folder. I am getting a `Run time Error 13` as soon as item not mail item, i.e.appointment, etc.

Follow-up question:

1) How do reply to all to a latest email based the subject and email could be in Inbox or sent items.

2) How to loop in all emails in a folder, i.e. clicking "Click here to view more on Microsoft edge" give you access to all old emails.

```
Sub AccessInbox2()

'Early binding

Dim Olook As Outlook.Application ' to access all the libraries of outlook
Dim OmailItem As Outlook.MailItem ' To access emails in the inbox
Dim ONameSpace As Outlook.Namespace ' it is class which opens the gate for you to access all outlook folders. Unlike the Folder class, it exactly tells VBA which folder to use.
Dim Fol As Outlook.Folder ' Where we have emails with attachments stored
Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment ' a class which will help us in dealing wiht emails which as attachements
Dim TotalEmails As Long
Dim i As Integer


Set Olook = New Outlook.Application
Set OmailItem = Olook.CreateItem(olMailItem) 'to deal with emails

'messaging application protocal interface
i = 1
For Each OmailItem In Olook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Goldy").Items

    'If TypeName(OmailItem) = "MailItem" Then
    If OmailItem.Class = 43 Then

    Sheet1.Cells(i, 7).Value = OmailItem.Subject

    End If

i = i + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [outlook VBA script run-time error 13 randomly while iterating emails in a public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098914/outlook-vba-script-run-time-error-13-randomly-while-iterating-emails-in-a-public). See how the accepted answer uses an `Object` variable, which it then tests the `Class` of. You are using `MailItem` variable in your `For Each` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your edits. I went through that query as well, hence, the inclusion of ('If TypeName(OmailItem) = "MailItem" ) but it didn't work. In addition, I requested help with additional questions.  I have already spent 10 hrs on these to figure out a solution but was not smart enough to find one.

Comment: Note my second sentence to fix your main problem.

Comment: The code does process few emails as soon as it encounters a meeting or appointment, I get this error. Also, I do not know how the code starts its sequence, i.e. which email it will process first. I was wondering if there is a way to control this. Sorry I learned VBA for outlook only two weeks ago.

Comment: There's one thing I'd suggest changing from the linked answer - I'd go with `TypeOf ... Is` instead of `TypeName`.

Comment: @Comintern I agree with `TypeOf`. I think the linked answer proposes that an `If TypeName` check is unnecessary if you're already checking that `.Class = 43`

Comment: Thanks Guys.. Now I understand based on the example from OM3R on what you guys meant. Can you please help me with the followup questions?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub AccessInbox2()
'Early binding
    Dim Olook As Outlook.Application ' to access all the libraries of outlook
    ' it is class which opens the gate for you to access
    ' all outlook folders. Unlike the Folder class,
    ' it exactly tells VBA which folder to use.

    Set Olook = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")



    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Olook.GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                     .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) _
                     .Folders("Goldy").Items

   Dim i As Long
   Dim LastRow As Long
   For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1

        If TypeOf Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Debug.Print Items(i).Subject ' Print on Immediate Window

            With Sht

                 LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                 Debug.Print .Cells(LastRow, 7).Address ' Print on Immediate Window
                .Cells(LastRow, 7).Value = Items(i).Subject

            End With

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Om3R..  this works very well.  Can I pick your brain on my other two followup questions?
1) How do reply to all to a latest email based on a selected subject and email could be in Inbox or sent items.

2) How to loop in all emails in a folder, i.e. clicking "Click here to view more on Microsoft edge" give you access to all old emails.

Comment: I edited your code to address this I am not sure how to post it. 
    Items.Sort "ReceivedTime", True 'to put them in order by date
    
        If TypeOf Items(1) Is Outlook.MailItem And Items(1).Restrict(sFilter) Then

Comment: I’m away from my computer now but will help later @DJSingh can you post new question on what you have and tried