# Code not executing because the object doesn't support the filter property

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am not able to filter the selected mail item by Subject. 
The issue is that

```
If TypeOf Items(1) Is Outlook.MailItem And Items(1).Restrict(sFilter) Then
```

is triggering the error

> Run time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Steps:

1. Loop through cells for different subject names
2. Search the inbox and Sentitem folders for the latest email for selected "Subject" as sometimes people do not respond to your email. So latest email is in the sent items and not in your inbox
3. select the latest email and reply to all
4. For the body of the email, I am running another function to get the required info.

The code:

```
Sub AccessInbox6()
'Early binding
    Dim Olook As Outlook.Application ' to access all the libraries of outlook

    Set Olook = New Outlook.Application
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim sSubject As String


  ' Restrict items and running the loop

    Sheet1.Range("A2").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "" 'Using this to loop over multiple cells containing subjects

        sSubject = ActiveCell.Value
        sFilter = "[Subject] = '" & sSubject & "'"


        Dim Items As Outlook.Items
        Set Items = Olook.GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                         .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 'Checking the inbox

        Dim Items2 As Outlook.Items
        Set Items2 = Olook.GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                         .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items 'Checking the sent items


        Items.Sort "ReceivedTime", True 'to put them in order by date
        Items2.Sort "ReceivedTime", True 'to put them in order by date or I should use "SentOn"
        'Items2.Sort "SentOn", True


        If Items.Item(1).ReceivedTime > Items2.Item(1).ReceivedTime Then 'Here I am checking which email is latest by date either in inbox or SentItems

            If TypeOf Items(1) Is Outlook.MailItem And Items(1).Restrict(sFilter) Then 'Getting error here - Here I am checking if the "Subject of the email matches with what I have in the excel sheet

                 Debug.Print Items(1).Subject ' Print on Immediate Window

                       With Items(1).ReplyAll
                            .Display
                            .Body = "Dear Someone" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & GetPSMUpdate2 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Sincerely," & vbNewLine & "XX-"

                            '.Attachments.Add Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Tracking Sheet.xlsx"

                            .To = "XXX@gmail.com"
                            .Subject = "PSM Report"
                            '.Send
                        End With
                        Else
                          MsgBox "No emails found with Subject:" & vbLf & "'" & sSubject & "'"

            End If


        Else

            If TypeOf Items2(1) Is Outlook.MailItem And Items2(1).Restrict(sFilter) Then

                 Debug.Print Items(1).Subject ' Print on Immediate Window

                       With Items(1).ReplyAll
                            .Display
                            .Body = "Dear Someone" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & GetPSMUpdate2 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Sincerely," & vbNewLine & "XX-"

                            '.Attachments.Add Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Tracking Sheet.xlsx"

                            .To = "XXX@gmail.com"
                            .Subject = "PSM Report"
                            '.Send
                        End With
                        Else
                          MsgBox "No emails found with Subject:" & vbLf & "'" & sSubject & "'"

            End If
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

End Sub
```

---

```
Function GetPSMUpdate2() As String

 Dim PSMColumn As Range, PSMRow As Range, r As Range, C As Range

 Dim Str As String

 Sheet2.Activate

 Set PSMColumn = Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    For Each r In PSMColumn

        Set PSMRow = Range(r, r.End(xlToRight))

        For Each C In PSMRow

            Str = Str & C.Value

            If C.Column < r.End(xlToRight).Column Then

            Str = Str & vbTab
            End If

        Next C

        If r.Row < Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row Then

            Str = Str & vbNewLine

        End If

    Next r

GetPSMUpdate2 = Str

End Function
```

Comment: Just a heads up (and likely unrelated to your issue), `Str` is a built in VBA function, so you should avoid using it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister duly noted. Actually, this code is built upon the logic from Om3r, bigben, and Comitern and they suggested to create a new question. I am not sure how to include them. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545326/code-not-executing-the-loop-due-to-run-type-error-13-outlook/54546154?noredirect=1#comment95913172_54546154)

Comment: They're more excel specialists... Since Excel is used in the code posted I've added the Excel tag to the question so they might see it (Comintern already has). Keep in mind that not everybody knows everything, so the same people may not be able to answer that could/did, before :-) That's also a reason that only one topic belongs in a question.

Comment: Can I see sample/example of your excel file?

Comment: @0m3r: what is the way to share the excel and new code. I reworked on this code and now I am able to find the latest email based on the subject in Inbox or Sent Items. However, the only issue now is that replyall is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Item in the variable names causes some confusion as well the filter could be separated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AccessInbox6Fix()

'Early binding
    Dim Olook As outlook.Application
    
    Dim ItemsRaw As outlook.Items
    Dim Items2Raw As outlook.Items
    
    Dim Items As outlook.Items
    Dim Items2 As outlook.Items
    
    Dim sFilter As String
    Dim sSubject As String
    
    Set Olook = New outlook.Application
    
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Select
    
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "" ' Loop over cells containing subjects
        
        'Checking the inbox
        Set ItemsRaw = Olook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
        Debug.Print "Raw counts"
        Debug.Print " ItemsRaw.Count: " & ItemsRaw.Count
                
        'Checking the sent items
        Set Items2Raw = Olook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items 
        Debug.Print " Items2Raw.Count: " & Items2Raw.Count

        sSubject = ActiveCell.Value
        sFilter = "[Subject] = '" & sSubject & "'"
        Debug.Print
        Debug.Print sFilter
        
        Debug.Print "Subject counts"
        Set Items = ItemsRaw.Restrict(sFilter)
        Debug.Print " Items.Count: " & Items.Count
        
        Set Items2 = Items2Raw.Restrict(sFilter)
        Debug.Print " Items2.Count: " & Items2.Count
        
        Items.Sort "SentOn", True
        Items2.Sort "SentOn", True

        If Items.Item(1).ReceivedTime > Items2.Item(1).ReceivedTime Then
            
            If TypeOf Items.Item(1) Is MailItem Then
            
                Debug.Print Items.Item(1).Subject

                With Items.Item(1).ReplyAll
                    .Display
                    .To = "XXX@noplacenowhere.com"
                    .Subject = "PSM Report"
                    '.Send
                End With
                
            Else
                MsgBox "Most recent item is not a mailitem:" & vbLf & "'" & sSubject & "'"

            End If

        Else

            If TypeOf Items2.Item(1) Is outlook.MailItem Then
            
                 Debug.Print Items2.Item(1).Subject ' Print on Immediate Window

                    With Items2.Item(1).ReplyAll
                        .Display
                        .To = "XXX@noplacenowhere.com"
                        .Subject = "PSM Report"
                        '.Send
                    End With
                    
                Else
                    MsgBox "Most recent item is not a mailitem:" & vbLf & "'" & sSubject & "'"
                    
            End If
            
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```